# MYSQL bearing (azimuth) calculation from two-point latitude and longitude returning NULL value

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble obtaining the degree value of the bearing from two points containing latitude and longitude. The mysql formula does  not return any error but the value it produces is always NULL.

Basically I have a set value for `@orig_lon` and `@orig_lat` as the origin latitude and longitude and a table named location_city_town containing the set of latitudes and longitudes to compare it with.

The task of the sql code below is to display everything from the table and display the computed bearing (azimuth) based on this formula:

θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )

where λ is the longitude and φ is the latitude.

The 360 value is just for normalization.

> `SELECT *, (360.0 + DEGREES(ATAN2(SIN(RADIANS(location_city_town.longitude -
>    @orig_lon)) * COS(RADIANS(location_city_town.latitude)), COS(RADIANS(@orig_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(location_city_town.latitude)) -
>    SIN(RADIANS(@orig_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(location_city_town.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(location_city_town.longitude - @orig_lon))))%360.0)
>   as azimuth FROM location_city_town;`

I'm stuck and need help badly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with the innermost query and check if it returns null. If not, check with the statement on the "upper" level and again check against null. That way You can check what exactly causes the value to be null.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - I assume you're talking about initial bearing, but maybe you can clarify.